# Сохранение сгенерированной страницы html

Tags: php, javascript, html

У меня есть страница с кучей JS скроптов(загрузка изображения, динамическая таблица, блоки которые перемещаются мышкой). Суть такая пользователь зашел заполнил таблицу(см рисунок), расставил блоки по местам, и из всего этого по кнопке сохранить надо создать страницу, как нибудь ее обозвать и положить на сервер. 
По сути на этой странице должно быть только сгенерированные таблицы и блоки со своими координатами.

Вопрос в том как средствами php или js выдернуть определенные div блоки создать html и положить содержимое div в созданный html или php файлик(тоесть таких файликов планируется, будет много).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как изменяемые данные только координаты и значения в таблице, то формируем универсальную страницу готовую принять данные и воспроизвести созданное пользователем поле из блоков. Это будет костяком страницы.  *Далее:*

**Старый проверенный способ:**

Итак имеем: "A" -массив  блоков.

Хранимая информация: номер блока, название, координаты.
массив "B" - значения ячеек таблицы. (добавляем столбец номер блока)

По кнопке сохранить отправляем POST-запрос на сервер имеющиеся у нас массивы "А" и "В" ( делается средствами js, рекомендую задействовать localstorage)

Принятая информация заносится в базу данных, с привязкой к пользователю.

Для воспроизведения повторно:

После авторизации на сайте, загружаем из базы данных значения, раставляем по координатам блоки, соответственно значения таблиц подтягиваем ajax  по мере надобности.

**Современный способ:**

Развертываем веб-сокеты, постоянно обмениваемся информацией с сервером.

Comment: Если у каждого пользователя своя личная страница, и остальные пользователи на неё влиять не могут, то web-socket для этой задачи overkill.

Comment: @Arnial, всегда стараюсь предусмотреть архитектуру свободной для полёта фантазии заказчика. Допустимое расширение - управление страницами несколькими пользователями.